# Am I using sound equational reasoning about a definition of filter in terms of foldr?

Tags: haskell, filter, fold, equational-reasoning

well, this is the definition of the filter function using foldr:

```
myFilter p xs = foldr step [] xs
    where step x ys | p x       = x : ys
                    | otherwise = ys
```

so for example let's say i have this function:

```
myFilter odd [1,2,3,4]
```

so it will be:

```
foldr step [] [1,2,3,4]
```

and this will be

```
step 1 (foldr step [] [2,3,4])
```

and this will be

```
step 1 (step 2 (foldr step [] [3,4]))
```

and this will be

```
step 1 (step 2 (step 3 (foldr step [] [4])))
```

and this will be

```
step 1 (step 2 (step 3 (step 4 (foldr step [] []))))
```

and `foldr step [] []` is `[]` so:

```
step 1 (step 2 (step 3 (step 4 [])))
```

now we will actually get into the `step` function.
here is the definition of `step` inside the `myFilter` function, from above:

```
step x ys | p x       = x : ys
          | otherwise = ys
```

also, i remind you that `p` is actually the `odd` function in our example.

well, again, we are here:

```
step 1 (step 2 (step 3 (step 4 [])))
```

and

`x = 4` in the most inner `step`, and `4` isn't odd, so we returning `ys`, which is `[]`

so now we get this:

```
step 1 (step 2 (step 3 []))
```

now, in the most inner `step`, `x = 3`, and `3` is odd, so we return `x:ys`, which is `3 : []`, which is `[3]`, and now we get:

```
step 1 (step 2 [3])
```

and now, in the inner `step`, `x = 2`, and `2` isn't odd, so we return `ys`, which is `[3]`, so now we will get:

```
step 1 [3]
```

and now, `x = 1`, and `1` is odd, so we return `x : ys`, which is `1 : [3]`, which is `[1,3]`.

The End :-).

am i right in all my moves?
thanks a lot :-).

p.s. the definition of `myFilter` is from the book [*Real World Haskell*](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/), in chapter 4.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks right to me on first read.

The important thing to remember though is that in order to achieve lazy evaluation, Haskell will actually look at things the other way. In other words, the real sequence is more like

```
step 1 (step 2 (step 3 (step 4 [])))
```

becomes

```
step 1 <block1>
```

which becomes

```
[1, <block1>]
```

then if you try to pull the next element from that list, it will evaluate

```
[1, step 2 <block2>]
```

which becomes

```
[1, <block2>]
```

and then trying to evaluate

```
[1, step 3 (step 4 [])]
```

turns into

```
[1, step 3 <block3>]
```

which becomes

```
[1, 3, <block3>]
```

etc. This took me a while to understand. It was counterintuitive to me that since `foldr` seems to be evaluated from the "inside out" but `foldl` is evaluated from the "outside in" that `foldr` would be lazy (which it is), whereas `foldl` is strict. But if you think of it the way I outlined above, it makes sense (to me, anyway).

Comment: thanks for that.
well, i'm very newbie in haskell, so i don't know all the "backstage" of haskell. i just needed to know if it's simply like this.
maybe in later chapters of the book, they will discuss about what you tried to teach me here (which i need to read more, to understand it)
thanks a lot :-).

Comment: I think you're on the right track. I wouldn't call this the "back end" so much as understanding how lazy evaluation works. For a simple case like this it doesn't matter, but when you come to see that `foldr` works on infinite lists and `foldl` doesn't, this will help you understand why.

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on the lazy evaluation order: Basically Haskell always evaluates the function first, not looking at the arguments until it has to.

If the result of the call to `myFilter` is used (for example printed), the function will be evaluated in the following order:

```
myFilter odd [1,2,3,4]
```

First the `myFilter` function is evaluated:

```
foldr step [] [1,2,3,4]
```

Now `foldr` is the outermost function and gets evaluated:

```
step 1 (foldr step [] [2,3,4])
```

Now `step` gets evaluated producing a `1`, since `1` is odd:

```
1 : foldr step [] [2,3,4]
```

Now the first element of the result list is available and can be used by the calling function. If the calling function also uses the following elements evaluation continues
with the `foldr`:

```
1 : step 2 (foldr step [] [3,4])
```

The evaluation of `step` now doesn't produce any new elements, since 2 is even:

```
1 : foldr step [] [3,4]
```

So `foldr` again:

```
1 : step 3 (foldr step [] [4])
```

Now evaluating `step` produces `3`:

```
1 : 3 : foldr step [] [4]
```

Evaluating `foldr`;

```
1 : 3 : step 4 (foldr step [] [])
```

And `step` once more:

```
1 : 3 : foldr step [] []
```

Finally `foldr` evaluates to an empty list:

```
1 : 3 : []
```

Comment: so what you say is that the recursion is realy not a recursion?
in your evaluation, everything is computed from the beginning to the end, and in the end, it's just give me the list.
what i understand, is that there is realy a recursion that at first go from start to the end of the input list, and after that, everything is computed from the inner `step` to the outer one.
i hope that it also will be explained in the book, in future reading :).
thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

At first glance, the steps you've taken in your specific example look correct individually. However, I'd like to point out that both `filter` and `foldr` can be usefully applied to *infinite lists*--which should indicate that the order of your steps is incorrect as far as Haskell is concerned.

Comment: thanks for that. i think that my comment to Dan, is also (sort of) for you.
:-).